# Keeping a value updated throughout many ViewController's in iOS using Swift

Tags: swift, struct, google-cloud-firestore, uiviewcontroller, global-variables

In my ViewController (VC1) I have the following variable:

```
var orderInfo: Order!
```

Order is a struct itself like the following:

```
struct Order {
    var orderId: String
    var orderReferenceNumber: String
    //more variables...
init(
        orderId: String,
        orderReferenceNumber: String,
){
        self.orderId = orderId
        self.orderReferenceNumber = orderReferenceNumber
}    
    init(data: [String: Any]){
        orderId = data[DatabaseRef.orderId] as? String ?? ""
        orderReferenceNumber = data[DatabaseRef.orderReferenceNumber] as? String ?? ""    
 }

    static func modelToData(order: Order) -> [String: Any] {

        let data : [String: Any] = [
            DatabaseRef.orderId: order.orderId,
            DatabaseRef.orderReferenceNumber: order.orderReferenceNumber,
]
        return data            
    }    
}
```

In VC1, I have a listener that updates its info from Firestore Database (throught addsnapshotslistener). When the variable `orderInfo` gets updated in VC1 because of a change in the order in the database the listener will update the `orderInfo` variable in VC1. While the user is in another ViewController (e.g. VC2), I would like to access `orderInfo` variable with its updated info from VC1. How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous of ways of doing that. Lets mention some of them.

1. You can use **NotificationCenter**

*Example*

```
class VC1: UIViewController {
    var orderInfo: Order! 

    func updateOrder() {
        var orderDict = ["orderInfo":orderInfo]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "orderInfoUpdated"), object: nil, userInfo: orderDict)
    }
}

// The receiving end
class VC2: UIViewController {
    var orderInfo: Order!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(doSomething(_: )), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "orderInfoUpdated"), object: nil)
    }

    func doSomething(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        if let orderInfo = notification.userInfo?["orderInfo"] as? Order {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

2. You can create an "app state" service where you use the **singleton
   pattern** making the user info accessible in all the views

*Example:*

```
class AppState {
    static let shared = AppState()
    var orderInfo: Order! 
    ...
}
```

On your ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    func doSomeWork() {
        print(AppState.shared.orderInfo)
    }
}
```

3. You can make it global (Not Recommended)